# Store array of settings into database row

Tags: java

I want to optimize into database row application settings. Something like this

```
10 - enabled option 1;
12 - enabled option 2;
13 - enabled option 3;
```

And the entire number is stored into database as 1073741823.

I tried to implement this:

public void test() {

```
    // Let's say you get a String representing your option from your database
    String optionFromDB= "132456";
    // optionFromDB is a number like "132456"
    // We transform it to bigDecimal:
    BigDecimal myOptions=new BigDecimal(optionFromDB);

    // Then we can use it.

    // enable the option X (X is a number)
    myOptions.setBit(2);

    // Disable option X
    myOptions.clearBit(2);

    // Save the options to the db:
    String newValToSave=myOptions.toString();

    // do something if option x enable:
    if (myOptions.testBit(123)){ 
        System.out.println("test");
    }       
}
```

How I can implement this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just use a number, let's call it *state*. The type should be decided according to the number of options that you will have. For instance if you have 10 options, `Integer` is more than enough. For each option you can use one bit of this integer state.

So to set the first option just set first bit, and in general the ith bit for the ith option. To see if the ith option is enabled check if the ith bit of the *state* is set.

#### Code key points

For setting the ith bit you can use the following code:

```
state |= 1 << i;
```

For testing the ith bit the following:

```
state & (1L << i)) != 0;
```

For clearing the ith bit use:

```
state &= ~(1 << i);
```

Comment: Can you show me some code example how to implement it?

Comment: Yes, in a second.

Comment: Can you please show me complete Java code with methods and etc.

Comment: It is, just use it according to needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assume value is an integer - this will give you 32 options. If that's not enough, you can take long (64 bits) or apply the same logic to any number of bits.

- To enable bit n: value |= 1 <<< n
- To disable bit n: value &= ~(1 <<< n)
- To test bit n: (value & (1 <<< n)) != 0
- To convert to string: String s = Integer.toString(value)
- To convert from string: value = Integer.parseInt(s)

Comment: This is Java example.

Comment: `public int enableBit(int value, int bit) { return value | (1 <<< n); }`. I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: I'm not sure how to ge the final result -> 1073741823